# Flip flop mechanism in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a flip flop type mechanism in pandas.

data3 is the output I'd like to create

data3 = 1 when data1 is a 1. Then stay a 1 until data2 signals a 1. Then continue as 0 until data1 signals a 1 again....etc.....

I could use `.iterrows()`, but I am wondering if there is a faster vectorized way?

```
data1 = [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
data2 = [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]
data3 = [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["d1"]= data1
df["d2"]= data2
```

Comment: what should be `data3` when `data1` and `data2` are both `1` at the very start?

Comment: That would be a zero, because data1 would make data3 a 1, but data2 would cancel it out to a zero

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
df['out'] = (
 df['d1'].map({1: True})
 .fillna(df['d2'].map({1: False}))
 .ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
 )

print(df)
```

If you want to give priority to d2 over d1 in case of equality:

```
df['out'] = (
 df['d2'].map({1: False})
 .fillna(df['d1'].map({0: True}))
 .ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
 )
```

Output:

```
    d1  d2  out
0    1   0    1
1    1   0    1
2    0   1    0
3    0   0    0
4    0   0    0
5    1   0    1
6    0   0    1
7    0   0    1
8    0   1    0
9    0   1    0
10   1   0    1
```

Comment: When I use: data1 = [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1] and data2 = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0] this gives an error.

Comment: Use `.ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)`